# Gridline marking for 90N and 90S not showing in cartopy

Tags: python, mapping, cartopy, gridlines

I am trying to make a map in Cartopy that displays a marking for each grid line. For some reason the 90N and 90S grid markings are not displaying. What am I doing wrong?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[15, 15])
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-180, -180, -90, 90])

ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, zorder=100)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, zorder=100)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, edgecolor='black', facecolor='none', zorder=11)

gl = ax.gridlines(xlocs=range(-180,181,30), ylocs=range(-90,91,30), color='black', linestyle='dotted', zorder=100, draw_labels=True)
gl.top_labels = False
gl.right_labels = False
gl.bottom_labels = True
gl.left_labels = True
plt.show()
```

**Map of Earth not displaying 90N/S**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. I had the same problem, I could not get the 90 degrees latitude values using the Cartopy gridlines. But following this example on the documentation, it is possible by directly manipulating the ticks of the axes.

The link to the Cartopy documentation with the example code is here:
https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/gridlines_and_labels/tick_labels.html

And I tried the same using the code below:

```
%matplotlib inline

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[15, 15])
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, edgecolor='black', facecolor='none')
ax.set_yticks([-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_xticks([-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120,180], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(LONGITUDE_FORMATTER)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(LATITUDE_FORMATTER)
ax.grid(color='black', linestyle='dotted')
plt.show()
```